# How to hide some fields to a login user in odoo

Tags: odoo

i'm working on some app, but need to hide some fields from login user.. Below is the code i've tried

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    grade_id = fields.Many2one(related='contract_id.grade_id', string='Grade')
    rank_id = fields.Many2one(related='contract_id.rank_id', string='Point')
```

And this other one is the view

```
<!-- Employees inherited views -->
<record id="view_employee_form_grade_rank" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">hr.employee.form.grade.rank</field>
    <field name="model">hr.employee</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="job_id" position="after">
            <field name="grade_id"/>
            <field name="rank_id" domain="[('grade_id','=',grade_id)]" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to achieve this:

- you could simply add `invisible="true"`and it would hide the field for everyone(including logged users) ;)
- you can use `<t t-if="uid is None">` your code `</t>` and this would hide from logged users
- you can also set security groups and allow only users from the particular group to see the field (documentation: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html)

The choice is yours. Let me know if this is what you've been looking for.

PS: I have used the second solution when I was working on my app that is hiding product price as well as "Add to cart" button until log in(https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/hide_price_shop/) and the code looked like:

```
<t t-if="uid is None">
          <p><a href="/web/login" class="btn btn-primary">Log In&amp;nbsp;to see price</a>&amp;nbsp;</p>
</t>
```